# Filling Missing data in shapefile using spatial interpolation python

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas, shapefile, spatial-interpolation

This is my first question. I am new to python so please bear with me.
I have a shapefile that contains data as given below.

```
ID   Data  geometry
111  0.1   POINT(X,Y)
112  0.2   POINT(X,Y)
113  0.5   POINT(X,Y)
114  NaN   POINT(X,Y)
115  0.3   POINT(X,Y)
116  NaN   POINT(X,Y)
117  NaN   POINT(X,Y)
```

I want to fill missing values in Column "Data" using spatial interpolation.
I have tried this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OfC3KpL4PRw but it adds a lot of extra coordinates to my data. Is there any simpler way to fill those missing points using spatial interpolation?

Comment: Scipy has a 2D interpolation module. But stack overflow isn't for library recommendations. You need have (nearly) working code and a specific issue. You might get better responses at gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

- you can work out complete distances matrix and use that to look up values of nearest points
- I would not expect this to scale to large numbers of points
- have simulated some data as question is abstract

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance
import numpy as np
import shapely.geometry

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres")).set_crs("EPSG:4326")

# get some points - UK boundary
gdf = gdf.loc[gdf["iso_a3"].eq("GBR"), "geometry"].apply(lambda g: g.geoms).explode().apply(
    lambda g: g.exterior.coords
).explode().apply(shapely.geometry.Point).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame().assign(
    data=lambda d: np.arange(0, len(d))
)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf)

# randomly set 10 values to NaN
gdf.loc[gdf.sample(20).index, "data"] = np.nan

# build matrix of distances...
d = pd.DataFrame(distance.cdist(*[np.stack(gdf.geometry.apply(lambda x: [x.x, x.y]))] * 2))

# take mean of nearest 3 co-ordinates
gdf["data_i"] = gdf.apply(
    lambda r: gdf.loc[d[r.name].sort_values().index, "data"].dropna().head(3).mean()
    if np.isnan(r["data"])
    else r["data"],
    axis=1,
)

gdf.plot(column="data")
gdf.plot(column="data_i")
```